# antiderivative of absolute value fanction

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

If I need to find a antiderivative function of a function, for example
$$
f(x) = \left|x^2-2x \right|
$$
Can I state that
$$
F(x) =  
\begin{cases}
x^3/3 - x^2 & \text{ for }x < 0, x > 2, \\
        -x^3/3 + x^2 &\text{ for }0 \leq x \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
Or am I not allowed to separate the function into parts like that, and then perform the integral on each part separately? I am concerned with points between the separated parts.

If I am not allowed, how can I solve such problems?

Comment: "am I not allowed to separate the function into parts" - I think in general this should always be allowed because 1) it makes the solution much easier, and b) it's really just another way of saying the same thing, so it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: So just a general hint: Remember that you want the antiderivative to be a **continuous** function. So consider the limits at the break points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, you just need to find *one* antiderivative and the others will differ from it by an additive constant.

What antiderivative? The fundamental theorem of calculus provides one! Set
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x |t^2-2t|\,dt
$$
and this will be it. Why $0$ as the “starting point”? Also $2$ would have been fine, other starting points are less well-behaved, because we have
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
t^2-2t & t\le 0 \\[6px] 2t-t^2 & 0\le t\le 2 \\[6px] t^2-2t & t\ge 2
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, for $x\le0$, we have
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x (t^2-2t)\,dt=\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2
$$
For $0\le x\le 2$, we have
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x (2t-t^2)\,dt=x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3
$$
For $x\ge2$, we have
$$
F(x)=F(2)+\int_2^x (t^2-2t)\,dt=\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+\frac{8}{3}
$$

Comment: wait, for x≤0, how is this integral valid? x < 0 aka it should be -∫0x(t2−2t)dt and not ∫x0(t2−2t)dt

Comment: @AvivAviv It’s perfectly valid. By definition, $\int_b^a=-\int_a^b$

Comment: yes but then the result should be with the minus... that is -1/3*x^3+x^2

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The method is fine. But when you do that, you need to make sure that $F$ is continuous, in particular at the separating points. Right now it’s continuous at $0$, but not at $2$, so you need to add an appropriate constant in the case $x>2$.